A question on the modes of convergence and their relationship
Let $\{ X_n \}$ be a sequence of RVs such that $X_n \sim N(0,\frac{1}{n})$. Let $F_n$ be the CDF of the each $X_n$.
Then, we can see that as $n \to \infty,$ the PMF of $X_n$ will increase without bound at $x=0$ and will go to $0$ at all other points, i.e., at $x \ne 0$.
With this understanding, I write $F_n \to F$ weakly, where
$$
F(t)=
\begin{cases}
0, & t<0 \\
1, & t \ge 0 \\
\end{cases}
.$$
Is this reasoning correct ?
My next question is this:

Is it true that $X_n \xrightarrow{L} 0$, i.e., $X_n \to 0$ in distribution ?
I am confused as to how to proceed as to because the definitions of weak convergence of CDF and convergence of RV in distributions are closely related.

Edit:
The convention in the book is like this:
Let $\{F_n \}$ be a sequence of CDFs. If there exists a CDF $F$ such that as $n \to \infty, F_n(x)\to F(x)$ at every point $x$ at which $F$ is continuous, we say that $F_n$ converges weakly to $F.$
And $X_n \xrightarrow{L} 0$ means $X_n \to 0$ in distribution.
If $\{ X_n \}$ is a sequence of RVs and $\{F_n \}$ is the corresponding sequence of CDFs, we say that $X_n $ converges in distribution to $X$ if there exists an RV $X$ with CDF $F$ such that $F_n \to F$ weakly.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

What does $X_n \xrightarrow{L} 0$ mean? Your definitions are not clear.

What is your definition of $F_n\to F$ weakly?

What will be the cdf of the random variable $X$ which is identically $0$? Is it related to $F$? or is it $F$ itself? If yes, then what can you say by the definition you gave in your question.

It is identically $F.$

So, from the definition, we have that $X_n \to X$ in distribution.

Your reasoning for $F_{n} \to F$ weakly is correct, since indeed $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{n}(x) = 0, \forall x < 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{n}(x) = 1, \forall x > 0$ (you don't have to consider $x=0$ since $F$ jumps here).
Then indeed you have $X_{n} \rightsquigarrow 0$, by taking 0 as the limiting random variable $X$ in your definition for convergence in distribution, as this will have the CDF $F$ that you described.
